# Firebase observing and taking values to an array

Tags: ios, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have five observing methods that takes five different INT values from Firebase. All the script is actually working. If I print the snapshot, the console shows me the five different values. Outside of the five observing methods, I have an array that is connected to a bar chart. I would like to take the first value and append it to the [0] of the array and so on.
This is my code:

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    var exampleString = (label.text?.lowercased())!
    ref2 = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref2.child("parole_chiave").child(exampleString).child(exampleString).child("valore1").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot.value!)

    })
    ref2.child("parole_chiave").child(exampleString).child(exampleString).child("valore2").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot.value!)

    })
    ref2.child("parole_chiave").child(exampleString).child(exampleString).child("valore3").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot.value!)

    })
    ref2.child("parole_chiave").child(exampleString).child(exampleString).child("valore4").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot.value!)

    })
    ref2.child("parole_chiave").child(exampleString).child(exampleString).child("valore5").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot.value!)

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one possible way to achieve your goal is to nest the observes inside one another, this will force the first observation to finish, and populate your array, before the second observation takes place.

```
ref2.child("parole_chiave").child(exampleString).child(exampleString).child("valore1").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

myArray.append(snapshot.value) as! Int
ref2.child("parole_chiave").child(exampleString).child(exampleString).child("valore2").observe(.value, with: { snapshot2 in

    myArray.append(snapshot2.value) as! Int
    ref2.child("parole_chiave").child(exampleString).child(exampleString).child("valore3").observe(.value, with: { snapshot3 in

        myArray.append(snapshot3.value) as! Int
        ref2.child("parole_chiave").child(exampleString).child(exampleString).child("valore4").observe(.value, with: { snapshot4 in

            myArray.append(snapshot4.value) as! Int
            ref2.child("parole_chiave").child(exampleString).child(exampleString).child("valore5").observe(.value, with: { snapshot5 in

                myArray.append(snapshot5.value) as! Int

            })

        })

    })

})
```

Note you will have to change the names of each snapshot, because they are now inside the same methods.